# pygame does not blit unless I call pygame.event.get()

Tags: python, macos, event-handling, pygame

After crashing my head against the monitor for 2 hours I realised that:

```
display.blit(mypic, posx, posy)
pygame.display.update()
```

would just not work (i.e. *wouldn't blit anything on the screen*) unless I call:

```
pygame.event.get()
```

Is this the weirdest bug on earth, or am I missing something?

I'm running pygame on python 2.7, mac os high sierra,
and yes I would be the least surprised if this was due to the goddam incompatibility between pygame and mac os.

Any hint about **what is going wrong here**?

Example code:

```
import pygame
winWidth = 800
winHeight = 600
posx = 200; posy = 200
mypic = pygame.image.load("path_to_my_picture.jpg")
COL_BACKGROUND = (255,255,255)

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((winWidth, winHeight))
pygame.init()
display.fill(COL_BACKGROUND)
display.blit(mypic, posx, posy)

# only including the following line it will blit the picture:
# pygame.event.get()

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how it works with mac but I am assuming it is similar to windows in that if you don't call `pygame.event.get()` regularly the operating system thinks that the window has stopped responding and no longer updates it.

This is mentioned under [pygame.event.pump()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) in the events page of the Pygame documentation

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call
>   to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact
>   with the rest of the operating system. If you are not using other
>   event functions in your game, you should call pygame.event.pump() to
>   allow pygame to handle internal actions.

Comment: but is this mentioned anywhere in the pygame documentation??

Comment: @DaniPaniz I know its a well known issue but I'm not sure if it is mentioned in the documentation, I will check,